# у меня однонаправленный список, как мне поменять местами максимальный и первый элемент?

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

макс элемент нашел, а как переприсвоить не знаю

```cpp
void List::Zamena() {
  element *max = Head;
  element *temp = Head;
  max = temp->x;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    if (max->x < temp->x) {
      max = temp;
      temp = temp->Next;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Поменять местами сами лист-ноды или значения в них?

Comment: мне нужно поменять значения местами
например, был список  12 24 11, надо чтобы стал 24 12 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну начнем с того, что максимальный элемент вы находите неправильно.

Далее, кроме максимального, нужно еще найти элемент, стоящий перед максимальным

```
void List::Zamena() {
  // Если список пустой, то выходим
  if (Head == NULL)
    return;
  element *max = Head;
  element *temp = Head;
  element *prev = NULL;
  element *prevMax = prev;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    // Если нашли элемент больший, чем текущий максимальный
    if (max->x < temp->x) {
      // то переприсваиваем максимальный и предыдущий перед максимальным
      max = temp;
      prevMax = prev;
    }
    // В любом случае переходим на следующий элемент
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->Next;
  }

  // Если максимальный элемент первый, то выходим
  if (max == Head)
    return;
  // Элемент перед максимальным указывает на первый элемент
  prevMax->next = Head;
  // сохраняем второй элеммент
  temp = Head->next;
  // бывший первый элемент указывает на элемент за максимальным
  Head->next = max->next;
  // максимальный элемент указывает на сохраненный второй
  max->next = temp;
  // первый элемент стал максимальным
  Head = max;
}
```

Если же нужно поменять только значения узлов, ко код сильно упрощается

```
void List::Zamena() {
  // Если список пустой, то выходим
  if (Head == NULL)
    return;
  element *max = Head;
  element *temp = Head;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    // Если нашли элемент больший, чем текущий максимальный
    if (max->x < temp->x) {
      // то переприсваиваем максимальный
      max = temp;
    }
    // В любом случае переходим на следующий элемент
    temp = temp->Next;
  }

  // Если максимальный элемент первый, то выходим
  if (max == Head)
    return;
  // сохраняем значение первого элемента
  int tempX = Head->x;
  // присваиваем первому элементу значение из максимального
  Head->x = max->x;
  // присваиваем максимальному элементу сохраненное значение из первого
  max->x = tempX;
}
```

Comment: как можно избавиться от этих ошибок: 
E2238 Multiple declaration for 'max'
E2344 Earlier declaration of 'max'

Comment: @Demosfen Я исправил ошибку